Why are Weyl's Equations composed of only first-order derivatives?
I'm studying the Weyl's Equations from Section 1.5 of Perkins' Introduction to High Energy Physics.

The author says this:

Dirac set out to formulate a wave equation symmetric in space and time, which was first-order in both derivatives:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}= \pm \left( \sigma_1\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} +\sigma_2\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} + \sigma_3\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}\right)
\end{equation}

Why first order in both derivatives? I see that the equation must be symmetric in spacetime for special relativity and that it should leave the equation unchanged on negating the wavefunction. But again, why first order in both derivatives?

Equations 2nd-order in time (like the Klein-Gordon Equation) yield negative energy solutions which are not consistent if interpreted as wave functions of physical particles (as Schroedinger and Dirac were trying to do).

Do you have a reference for this? Because I thought negative energy solutions were supposed to be interpreted as antiparticles?

In fact, I even find it hard to digest something like negative energy:|

Yes, that is the field theoretic interpretation, which is how the KG equation is salvaged. Googling will find tons of references. Most intro field theory texts discuss this.
